# Returns a value as an output parameter

Tags: c, parameters, output

I have a question in C where I need to insert coefficients of a quadratic equation into a function and return the number of solutions and result.

> Write a program that accepts a series of 3 real numbers, which are the
>   coefficients of a quadratic equation, and the program will print out
>   some solutions to the equation and the solutions themselves. 
>   **Guidelines**:
>
> - Functions must be worked with one of the functions that
>     returns the number of solutions as a returned value, and returns the
>     solutions themselves through output parameters.
> - 3 numbers must be
>     received each time. The input will be from a file (will end in EOF)

In the meantime I built the function without reading from a file just to see that it works for me, I built the function that returns the number of solutions but I got entangled in how to return the result as output parameter
here is my code for now:

---

```
int main ()
{

    double a, b, c, root1,root2,rootnum;

    printf("Enter coefficients a, b and c: ");

    scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&a, &b, &c);

    rootnum=(rootnumber(a,b,c);

    printf("the number of roots for this equation is %d ",rootnum);
}


int rootnumber (double a,double b, double c)
{

    formula=b*b - 4*a*c;

    if (formula<0)

        return 0;

    if (formula==0)

        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

Comment: `else return 2` => `else return 2;` and `printf("the number of roots for this equationis ")`=> `printf("the number of roots for this equationis ");` also `rootnum=(rootnumber(a,b,c);` => `rootnum=rootnumber(a,b,c);`

Answer (score 1):

In C, providing an "output parameter" usually amounts to providing an argument that is a pointer.   The function dereferences that pointer and writes the result.   For example;

```
 int some_func(double x, double *y)
 {
     *y = 2*x;
     return 1;
 }
```

The caller must generally provide an address (e.g. of a variable) that will receive the result.   For example;

```
 int main()
 {
     double result;
     if (some_func(2.0, &result) == 1)
        printf("%lf\n", result);
     else
        printf("Uh oh!\n");
     return 0;
 }
```

I've deliberately provided an example that illustrates what an "output parameter" is, but has not relationship to the code you actually need to write.   For your problem, you will need to provide two (i.e. a total of five arguments, three that you are providing already, and another two pointers that are used to return values to the caller).

Since this is a homework exercise, I won't explain WHAT values your function needs to return via output parameters.  After all, that is part of the exercise, and the purpose is for you to learn by working that out.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a wayward parenthesis in the call and some other syntax errors, what you have so far looks fine. To print out the number of roots, you need to put a [format specifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) and an argument in your `printf` statement:

```
printf("the number of roots for this equation is %d\n", rootNum);
```

The `%d` is the format specifier for an int.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rootnumber (double a,double b, double c)
{
    double formula = (b*b) - (4*(a)*(c));
    if (formula > 0) {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (formula < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    double a, b, c;
    printf("Enter coefficients a, b and c: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&a, &b, &c);
    printf("The number of roots for this equation is %d ", rootnumber(a,b,c));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It just need some sanity checking, its working now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int rootnumber(double a, double b, double c);
int main ()
{

    double a, b, c, root1,root2;
    int rootnum;

    printf("Enter coefficients a, b and c: ");

    scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&a, &b, &c);

    rootnum=rootnumber(a,b,c);

    printf("the number of roots for this equation is %d", rootnum);

    return 0;
}


int rootnumber(double a, double b, double c)
{

    int formula= (b*b) - (4*a*c);

    if (formula<0)

        return 0;

    if (formula==0)

        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks , i fixed the missing ";" but this isn't my problem